# How to implement my own function to verify a SM2 signature?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature

In my work,I have to use Chinese SM2 encryption algorithm to sign a pdf and verify the signature,and I choosed itext to help my work.But as it's the first time I use itext lib, I'm so unfamiliar with it.

The signing part I used external signing ,putting a SM2 signature into a pdf's signature dictionary.I can find a lot of code on the Internet about this.But when it comes to verifying the signature , I can find little help(itext doesn't support SM2 algorithm, that's why I can't use the standart Verify method and must implement my own function to verify a SM2 signature).I mean I don't know how to get the signed origin data, as I do in the signing part using "GetRangeStream",and I don't know how to read the SM2 signature from the pdf's form field.

Could anyone give me some help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I use itextsharp 5.5.8

Comment: Text is much easier to read if there are blank lines used to break it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need obviously is similar to the code the iText method `AcroFields.VerifySignature` executes while creating the `PdfPKCS7` object representing the signature in question. As iText is open source, you can simply copy that code as far as you need it!

E.g.

> I don't know how to read the SM2 signature from the pdf's form field.

`AcroFields.VerifySignature` starts like this:

```
    virtual public PdfPKCS7 VerifySignature(String name) {
        PdfDictionary v = GetSignatureDictionary(name);
        if (v == null)
            return null;
        PdfName sub = v.GetAsName(PdfName.SUBFILTER);
        PdfString contents = v.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS);
        PdfPKCS7 pk = null;
        if (sub.Equals(PdfName.ADBE_X509_RSA_SHA1)) {
            PdfString cert = v.GetAsString(PdfName.CERT);
            if (cert == null)
                cert = v.GetAsArray(PdfName.CERT).GetAsString(0);
            pk = new PdfPKCS7(contents.GetOriginalBytes(), cert.GetBytes());
        }
        else
            pk = new PdfPKCS7(contents.GetOriginalBytes(), sub);
```

Thus, the essential code to extract the embedded signature object is like this

```
AcroFields acroFields = reader.AcroFields;
PdfDictionary v = acroFields.GetSignatureDictionary(name);
if (v != null) {
    PdfString contents = v.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS);
    byte[] embeddedSignatureObjectBytes = contents.GetOriginalBytes();
    [... process embeddedSignatureObjectBytes ...]
}
```

Beware: As the **Contents** string is padded with zeros, the `embeddedSignatureObjectBytes` bytes after the actual signature object will contain a tail of 0x00 bytes.

> I don't know how to get the signed origin data

`AcroFields.VerifySignature` continues like this:

```
UpdateByteRange(pk, v);
```

`AcroFields.UpdateByteRange` is implemented like this:

```
private void UpdateByteRange(PdfPKCS7 pkcs7, PdfDictionary v) {
    PdfArray b = v.GetAsArray(PdfName.BYTERANGE);
    RandomAccessFileOrArray rf = reader.SafeFile;
    Stream rg = null;
    try {
        rg = new RASInputStream(new RandomAccessSourceFactory().CreateRanged(rf.CreateSourceView(), b.AsLongArray()));
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int rd;
        while ((rd = rg.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0) {
            pkcs7.Update(buf, 0, rd);
        }
    } finally {
        if (rg != null) rg.Close();
    }
}
```

Thus, the essential code to read the signed document bytes is like this

```
AcroFields acroFields = reader.AcroFields;
PdfDictionary v = acroFields.GetSignatureDictionary(name);
if (v != null) {
    PdfArray b = v.GetAsArray(PdfName.BYTERANGE);
    RandomAccessFileOrArray rf = reader.SafeFile;
    Stream rg = null;
    try {
        rg = new RASInputStream(new RandomAccessSourceFactory().CreateRanged(rf.CreateSourceView(), b.AsLongArray()));
        [... process the signed data in the Stream rg ...]
    } finally {
        if (rg != null) rg.Close();
    }
}
```